# Kubuntu 22.04 - konsole / bash no colors

Tags: bash, kubuntu, colors, konsole

I have a fresh kubuntu 22.04 installation.

In konsole all characters are displayed in the same color.

I used different color schemes but only one color is used.

I noted that in 22.04 the ~/.bashrc file disappeared.

Also in /etc/bash.bashrc file seems that there is nothing related to colors.

Adding the line "color_promp=yes" in this file does nothing.

What can I do to have colors as in kubuntu 20.04 ?

Comment: what is your `TERM` environment variable set to? (`echo $TERM` output)

Comment: echo $TERM
xterm-256color

Comment: which characters should be in different colors but aren't? Your prompt is set in the `PS1` variable, and there are special codes for different colors. If you want `ls` to output in color, alias is to `ls --color=auto`

Comment: Ok So it is a bash setting problem. The ls --color=auto works as expected. Seems that the bash settings changed in the 22.04 version. I'll try to find an old 20.04 configuration for bash.

Comment: SOLVED: it was a missing ~/.bashrc in 22.04. I copied the file from a 20.04 installation

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:

it was a missing ~/.bashrc file in 22.04.

I copied the ~/.bashrc file from a 20.04 installation